# Vue component rendered out as comment?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to include a Vue npm package called [Vue Carousel](https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel) as a component in my project.

[This specific example of how to use the component employs a template string for its template](https://jsfiddle.net/quinnssense/hwutbyb8/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=hwutbyb8), so I've tried to include this component in the same way.

`carousel.vue`:

```
<script>
    import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue-carousel'

    const buildSlideMarkup = (count) => {
        let slideMarkup = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            slideMarkup += '<slide><span class="label">' + i + '</span></slide>'
        }
    return slideMarkup;
    };

    export default {
        name: 'testcarousel',
        template: '<div><carousel :navigationEnabled="true">' + buildSlideMarkup(10) + '</carousel></div>',
        Carousel,
        Slide
    }
</script>
```

I then try to include this component in my main component, `app.vue`:

```
<style scoped src="./app.css"></style>
<template src="./app.html"></template>

<script>
  import testcarousel from '../carousel/carousel'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: { testcarousel }
  }
</script>
```

I assumed the component would be ready to use within `app.html` at this point:

```
<div id="app">
    <testcarousel />
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I don't see the carousel displayed in the browser, and the component appears to be commented out in the DOM, appearing like this:

```
<!--function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); }-->
```

I also get this error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the
>   template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
>   into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

After doing some research, it seems that [I will need to have the runtimeCompiler option set to true](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler), but after adding a `vue.config.js` with this setting:

```
module.exports = {
    runtimeCompiler: true,
}
```

..I'm not seeing any changes. I don't have Webpack installed in this project. Do I need to do that to make this work? Bonus dumb question: will it affect my project if I install Webpack after the initial project creation?

Comment: [See webpack configuration](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)

Comment: Taking a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot about Vue.use(VueCarousel). Add Vue.use(VueCarousel) before:

```js
    export default {
        name: 'testcarousel',
        template: '<div><carousel :navigationEnabled="true">' + buildSlideMarkup(10) + '</carousel></div>',
        Carousel,
        Slide
    }
```

If this won't work  try to **recreate your project with vue-cli** and choose **WEBPACK** option it should work.

Comment: I have `Vue.use(VueCarousel)` in my `main.js`, which seems to not be causing any problems

Comment: did you imported Vue Carousel in your main.js file ?

Comment: Yes. I think the carousel is working, but it's an issue with trying to use a template string and the `template: ...` syntax inside the `export`, which someone linked to this above: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only -- trying to figure this out now

Comment: Hmm if you will not find answer try to recreate your project with vue-cli and webpack option it should work i think

Comment: Yes I added webpack and it seems to be working now. I guess I was just confused because I have all these config files (`vue.config.js`, `babel.config.js`, and now `webpack.config.js`) -- didn't know if these would interfere with each other, but it seems to be working after installing webpack. Thanks for the help, I'm gonna upvote your answer

Comment: Thank you and have fun with Vue ;P

Comment: The key to note that it works because of using `template`. Basic idea is to use webpack configuration to fix the issue.